# Checking if $Z$ is an F-distribution using change of variable technique

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Two independent random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the following pdf

$f(x_1,x_2)= e^{-x_1-x_2}$ for $x_1, x_2>0$, and $0$, otherwise. 
Using the change of variable technique, determine whether $Z=X_1 X_2^{-1}$ has an F-distribution. If it has, state its degrees of freedom and hence $var(Z)$.

I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to go about this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d standard exponential, so $2X_1$ and $2X_2$ are i.i.d $\chi^2_2$. Hence $\frac{2X_1/2}{2X_2/2}\sim F_{2,2}$ by definition of F distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what "change of variables" I can use in computing, but we have for $z \in \def\R{\mathbf R}\R$, $z \ge 0$
\begin{align*}
  \def\P{\mathbf P}\P(Z < z) &= \int_{\{x \in \R^2 \mid x_i > 0, x_1 < zx_2\}} f(x)\, dx\\
    &= \int_{(0,\infty)} \int_{(0,zx_2)} \exp(-x_1-x_2)\, dx_1\, dx_2\\
    &= \int_{(0,\infty)} \int_{(0, zx_2)} \exp(-x_1)\, dx_1 \exp(-x_2)\, dx_2\\
    &= \int_{(0,\infty)} \left[-\exp(-x_1)\right]_0^{zx_2}\, \exp(-x_2)\, dx_2\\
    &= \int_{(0,\infty)} \bigl(1 - \exp(-zx_2)\bigr)\,\exp(-x_2)\, dx_2\\
    &= \int_{(0,\infty)} \exp(-x_2) - \exp\bigl(-(z+1)x_2\bigr)\, dx_2\\
    &= 1 - \frac 1{z+1}
\end{align*}
To compute the density function of $Z$, we take the derivative, hence
$$ f_Z(z) = \frac 1{(z+1)^2}, \qquad z \ge 0 $$